# Ruby script can't use gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a tiny, plain (i.e. non-Rails) Ruby project that I'm trying to get to work with the `addressable` gem. Here's what happens:

```
$ ruby -r rubygems sign.rb
sign.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- addressable (LoadError)
    from sign.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

This is the `Gemfile`:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "addressable", "~> 2.3.2"
```

This is `sign.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require "addressable"
```

That's all there is to it. Why doesn't it want to use the gem?

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `addressable` file that you can require, just the [`addressable` directory](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/tree/addressable-2.3.2/lib). You need to require the specific file under that directory you want, e.g.:

```
require 'addressable/uri'
uri = Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/path/to/resource/")
# etc ...
```

or

```
require "addressable/template"
template = Addressable::Template.new("http://example.com/{?query*}/")
# etc...
```

Check out the [`addressable` docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the gem previously by using `$ bundle install` ?

This will fetch the gems specified in your Gemfile and make them available to the working directory.

Comment: And the installation was successful? Have you tried using `$ bundle exec` ? http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html EDIT: Nevermind, looks like Matt has got it.